# RemoveDuplicates function - how can I set multiple columns?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to use the `RemoveDuplicates` function using `Excel.Interop`, but I'm stuck as to how to pass it the column array. I already know that I cannot pass it as a simple `int[]` array, as it gives an exception at runtime, and that I can pass a single integer and it works, but I want to be able to select which columns to use at runtime.

My current code in C# looks like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void removeDuplicates(Excel.Application excelApp, Excel.Range range, int[] columns)
{
    range.RemoveDuplicates(excelApp.Evaluate(columns), 
        Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo); 
}
```

And it works fine if using only one column, but if the `columns` array has more than one value, only the first one is used.

In VBA, the equivalent function would be:

```
Sub RemoveBadExample()
    Dim colsToUse
    colsToUse = Array(1, 2)
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Evaluate(colsToUse), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Which also fails to use both columns. however, if I change it to this:

```
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(colsToUse), Header:=xlYes
```

It works just fine. I guess my question then is what is the equivalent in C#?

Comment: What happens if you remove the use of Evaluate, just columns as the first argument?

Comment: If I use an `int` array and pass it as it is, I get the following exception: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This test run worked for me in a unit test using 4.5 etc.  It did not throw an exception at any rate.

```
        Application app = new Application();
        Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Data\\ABC.xlsx",
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];
        Range rng = ws.Range["A1:C5", Type.Missing];
        object cols = new object[]{1, 2};
        rng.RemoveDuplicates(cols, XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

Be aware that excel cell indices that define ranges are 1 based, not zero.  So if you are passing in a bad range it will throw that kind of exception.

```
Object temp = range.Cells[1][1].Value;
```

Comment: I see some posts that do it like: Columns:= New Object() {1, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: Thanks! Using an `object` array instead of an `int` array it worked.

Comment: @Ted: Hi Ted! I know that's too late to ask but still. Can you please tell me how will I assign values to `cols` dynamically depending on the column count? Say if `sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` returns 20 than I want 20 entries. Can you please help? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Ashish, you can just do a for loop like int count = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; object cols = new object[count]; for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){ object[i] = i+1; } and then pass it in as the parameter.