# Delete duplicate rows from excel with HSSF POI

Tags: c#, excel, poi-hssf, hssf

So i have a file which comes from a third party which we edit and save with our application. We use HSSF library for that. Now that file comes with some of the duplicate rows and when we edit it, it edits on all the duplicate lines. So when we try to upload back to our payrol it giving us false result because there are duplicate values. 
Is there any better way to delete those duplicate rows? I dont want to loop through all the rows and delete duplicates.

Comment: It will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707182/removeduplicates-function-how-can-i-set-multiple-columns

Comment: @bjan i saw that but thats excel.interop library. I am not using that. Thank you though,

Comment: Then, AFAIK, the only option is to loop through records